# libcudart.so.5.5, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so

Tags: c++, opencv, centos, caffe

My computer is CentOS system, I try to **install caffe**. after install some dependencies. I run `$make all`, then it return following warning:

```
NVCC src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.cu
NVCC src/caffe/solvers/rmsprop_solver.cu
NVCC src/caffe/solvers/adam_solver.cu
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
CXX tools/test_net.cpp
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/test_net.bin
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcudart.so.5.5, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so, may conflict with libcudart.so.6.0
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.cpp
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.bin
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcudart.so.5.5, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so, may conflict with libcudart.so.6.0
```

I check the version of cuda: `$nvcc -V`, it return:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_17_18:36:13_PDT_2013
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.5, V5.5.0
```

I enter **/usr/local**, it shows:
[wathet blue cuda file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUFE1.png), I enter the *usr/local/cuda/lib*, there is **libcudart.so.6.0** in it! But the **libcudart.so.5.5** file is in the */usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib*. I do not know how to make `libcudart.so.5.5, needed by /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so`. So how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your `opencv` is built with cuda support and which was linked with cuda 5.5. Please try this command to be sure about the dependencies

`ldd /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so`

...if opencv is depended on cuda 5.5 please build your caffe with cuda 5.5 or you need to build opencv on your machine from source code when it will automatically find cuda 6.0

Comment: ```
[jiadan@k20-2 lib]$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff9f3ff000)
 libz.so.1 => /home/jiadan/anaconda2/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9bfce0d000)
 libcudart.so.5.5 => /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/libcudart.so.5.5 (0x00007f9bfcbbf000)
 libnppc.so.5.5 => /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/libnppc.so.5.5 (0x00007f9bfc95c000)
 libnppi.so.5.5 => /usr/local/cuda-5.5/lib64/libnppi.so.5.5 (0x00007f9bf4a09000)
```